# Replicate a list to create a list-of-lists

Tags: r, list, nested-lists

I am trying to create a list with the following (nested) structure:

```
l <- list()
for(i in seq(5)) l[[i]] <- list(a=NA,b=NA)
> str(l)
List of 5
 $ :List of 2
  ..$ a: logi NA
  ..$ b: logi NA
 $ :List of 2
  ..$ a: logi NA
  ..$ b: logi NA
 $ :List of 2
  ..$ a: logi NA
  ..$ b: logi NA
 $ :List of 2
  ..$ a: logi NA
  ..$ b: logi NA
 $ :List of 2
  ..$ a: logi NA
  ..$ b: logi NA
```

I'd like to do this via `rep` or similar, as I'm creating a whole bunch of blank lists which I will later fill in.  (I'm aware that I can just expand a list via referring to its next index, but that doesn't work when indexing two-deep).

I thought that `rep` worked for this, but it does not appear to.  `?rep` gives the following example:

```
fred <- list(happy = 1:10, name = "squash")
rep(fred, 5)
```

Which returns:

```
> str(rep(fred, 5))
List of 10
 $ happy: int [1:10] 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
 $ name : chr "squash"
 $ happy: int [1:10] 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
 $ name : chr "squash"
 $ happy: int [1:10] 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
 $ name : chr "squash"
 $ happy: int [1:10] 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
 $ name : chr "squash"
 $ happy: int [1:10] 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
 $ name : chr "squash"
```

In other words, it flattens the list.

I've also tried `list( rep(fred,5) )` which similarly fails.

How do I replicate a list-of-lists?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I think this has to do with rep behavior, you want to nest before you rep:

```
rep(list(fred),5)
```

The `str` output:

```
List of 5
 $ :List of 2
  ..$ happy: int [1:10] 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
  ..$ name : chr "squash"
 $ :List of 2
  ..$ happy: int [1:10] 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
  ..$ name : chr "squash"
 $ :List of 2
  ..$ happy: int [1:10] 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
  ..$ name : chr "squash"
 $ :List of 2
  ..$ happy: int [1:10] 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
  ..$ name : chr "squash"
 $ :List of 2
  ..$ happy: int [1:10] 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
  ..$ name : chr "squash"
```

Comment: Is it just me or is that horridly non-intuitive?  Thanks for the solution.

Comment: @AriB.Friedman -- It may make more sense if you compare `rep(1:2, 5)` and `rep(list(1:2), 5)` while keeping in mind that a list **really is** a type of vector. Does that help?

Comment: @JoshO'Brien Yeah, that does actually.

Answer (score 5):

You can use `replicate`:

```
l <- replicate(5, list(a=NA,b=NA), simplify=FALSE)
```

Comment: Do you know of a way to replicate the structure of an existing object? E.g. I have a list, which contains several levels of nesting, I would like an empty version for storing results, using the same names for each nested element. Maybe there is a way to delete all _data_ from entire object, leaving only the structure and its element names?